# Change UTC time to YYYY-MM-DD in R

Tags: r

I have a pretty basic question.

I have data formatted in this way:

```
2018-10-30 00:00:00 UTC
```

and need to convert it to be

```
2018-10-30
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe look at the docs for whatever you're using to obtain that object (POSIXct?) to see how to convert it. Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `as.Date`, the `format` you want is ISO 8601 that is default:

```r
date <- "2018-10-30 00:00:00 UTC"

as.Date(date, tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "2018-10-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>